# Compilation error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

Tags: make

I encountered with this error while attempted compiling fasta36 on my Ubuntu 12.04.3 64 bit machine:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [fasta36] Error 1
```

I used following command:

```
make -f ../make/Makefile.linux64_sse2
```

I guessed it could be due to absence or broken symbolic link so tried to find the correct file. I could see in my `/usr/lib` directory following files:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Nov 18  2011 libzbar.so.0 -> libzbar.so.0.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 187480 Nov 18  2011 libzbar.so.0.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Nov 12 18:54 libzeitgeist-1.0.so.1 -> libzeitgeist-1.0.so.1.1.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 122048 May  4  2012 libzeitgeist-1.0.so.1.1.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Nov 12 18:54 libzephyr.so.4 -> libzephyr.so.4.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55672 Apr 30  2011 libzephyr.so.4.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Nov 26  2010 libzvbi-chains.so.0 -> libzvbi-chains.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60112 Nov 26  2010 libzvbi-chains.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Nov 26  2010 libzvbi.so.0 -> libzvbi.so.0.13.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 546768 Nov 26  2010 libzvbi.so.0.13.1
```

I have no idea which one of these represent the `-lz`?

Could someone help me sort this one out here? I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

That would be libz.so that you are missing, or are just failing to pick up.

```
$ locate libz
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
```

If present, fix the library search path in the makefile.
If missing, install it (maybe a devl package) from:

```
$ apt-file search libz.so
lib32z1: /usr/lib32/libz.so.1
lib32z1: /usr/lib32/libz.so.1.2.3.4
lib32z1-dev: /usr/lib32/libz.so
lsb-build-base3: /usr/lib/lsb3/libz.so
zlib1g: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
zlib1g: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
zlib1g-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.4
zlib1g-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
zlib1g-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib32/libz.so.1.2.3.4
zlib1g-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
```